# Move Site Collections Based on Content Database

Tags: migration, content-database

I have a content DB which is growing huge and so I want to move Different Site Collections to Different Content Databases based on the Managed path that Site collection belongs to .Can some one Help me with this

The script I presently have is helpful to move the site collections based on the Web Application But i want to do it based on the Content Database something like below

```
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase "WSS_Content_"| foreach($site in $_.sites)
```

Can some one Help me with this

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see all site collection in that Content db then use this,

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All  -ContentDatabase contentdbname | select url, @{label="Size";Expression={$_.usage.storage}}
```

[Find SC in a Content DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609964/how-to-see-all-site-collections-in-a-specific-content-db)

You can use this PS command to move site collection to a different content database, however make sure you have sufficient permissions as described in this article,

[Move site collections between databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> Moving site collections between content databases You can use the
>   Windows PowerShell command Move-SPSite to move site collections
>   between content databases. Two procedures are provided here. The first
>   procedure moves a single site collection to a new content database,
>   and the second procedure moves multiple site collections to a new
>   content database. To move a single site collection At the Windows
>   PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:

```
Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```

> Where: `<http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName>` is
>   the name of the site collection.
>
> `<DestinationContentDb>` is the name of
>   the destination content database.

To move multiple site collections

```
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase <SourceContentDb> | Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```